# FileReader class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, filereader

I am trying to add up different lines of a text file, however, not all the lines are doubles (some lines have special characters), I have to add up all the double values. However, I keep getting this

> ERROR:class, interface, or enum expected

for the `isDouble` method. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class quiz4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File input = new File("mystery.txt");
        try
        {
            double answer = 0;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(input);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String currentLine = br.readLine();
            while (currentLine != null)
            {
                currentLine = br.readLine();
                if (isDouble(currentLine))
                {
                    double temp = Double.parseDouble(currentLine);
                    answer = currentLine + temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    public static boolean isDouble(String cu)
    {
        try
        {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(cu);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `answer = currentLine + temp;` is wrong. You can't assign a `String` to a `Double`. Also it looks like you have one too many brackets and your method isn't inside the class.

Comment: Because of unbalanced curly brackets, your `isDouble` method is **outside** of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **I really suggest you use an IDE** like [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), etc. They'll help you check your syntax error and give you very precise suggestions.

As the other answers suggest, your program has several problems.

1. The first letter of your `class` name should be a capital;
2. You can't assign a `String` to a `Double`;
3. Because of unbalanced curly brackets, your `isDouble` method is **outside** of the class

The following code should solve your problems.

```
    public class Quiz4 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            File input = new File("mystery.txt");
            try {
                double answer = 0;
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(input);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String currentLine = br.readLine();
                while (currentLine != null) {
                    currentLine = br.readLine();
                    Double curDouble = tryParseDouble(currentLine);
                    if (curDouble != null) {
                        answer += curDouble;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static Double tryParseDouble(String str) {
            try {
                return Double.parseDouble(str);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isDouble(String cu)` method is not within the class :

```
catch(Exception e){}
    } //closing brace for main method
} //closing brace for the class
public static boolean isDouble(String cu){
```

Just make sure the closing braces are balanced after this method.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problems

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class quiz4{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File input = new File("mystery.txt");
        try{
            double answer = 0;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(input);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String currentLine = null;
            while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                if(isDouble(currentLine)){
                    double temp = Double.parseDouble(currentLine);
                    answer = Double.parseDouble(currentLine) + temp;
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

        public static boolean isDouble(String cu){
            try {
            double value = Double.parseDouble(cu);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```